# How can I programatically close an iPad app?

Tags: ipad

When I press the Home button it doesn't fully close, but resides in memory. I would like to restart an app from scratch and not keep its latest state.

How can I programatically close when the home button is pressed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get your app to close when the home button is pressed you need to add an entry for `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to your `Info.plist`. This causes the app to revert to pre-4.0 behaviour which is as you describe.

Comment: Yeah, I made the non-programmer assumption, in part because I couldn't remember `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` precisely. :)